# How do I make Rigidbody movements in a first person shooter in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d, game-physics, rigid-bodies

So I am making an FPS game in Unity, and I used to use transform.translate for movement, but that allows the player to move through walls if moving fast enough (diagonal movement) and it doesn't even matter how large the wall's hitbox is.

Here's my Player Controller code:

https://pastebin.com/6g7j8G6v

Here's the movement code:

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    myBody.MovePosition(transform.position + (transform.forward * 
    Time.deltaTime * speed));
}

void Update()
{

float axisX = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
float axisY = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");
```

More info: With this code, the player now moves in very specific directions, regardless of rotation. Also, W and S moves up and down rather than forwards & backwards.

Comment: Please edit the question, and include all the code into the snippet, to improve readability

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to checkout https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/environment-and-player?projectId=5c51479fedbc2a001fd5bb9f#5c7f8529edbc2a002053b786 unity official documentation

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed;

    private Rigidbody rb;

    void Start ()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate ()
    {
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");

        Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);

        rb.AddForce (movement * speed);
    }
}
```

They have a pretty straight forward sample code on how to do it, bear in mind that this solution still needs to normalize the vectorial movement, and for that, do this:

```
rb.AddForce (movement.normalized  * speed);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public float speed;
public float rotationspeed;
 
void Update()
{
    transform.Translate(Vector3.up * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
    {

        transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 0, -1) * rotationspeed * Time.deltaTime);

    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
    {

        transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 0, 1) * rotationspeed * Time.deltaTime);

    }
}
public void restar()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).